# Why PHP try... catch (Exception) does not catch exception raised by inconv() in Yii2 application?

Tags: php, exception, yii2, try-catch

I have PHP code (that is running from Yii2 application):

```
    public static function convertNotes($notes) {
        if(is_null($notes)) {
            return $notes;
        }
        $tmp = 'Multibyte conversion error';
        try {
            $tmp = iconv('UTF-16LE', 'UTF-8', $notes); 
        } catch (Exception $ex) {
            $tmp = 'Multibyte conversion error: '+$ex->message;
        }
        return $tmp;
    }
```

Code tries to convert UTF16LE string (coming from database) into UTF8 string. Sometimes the input string is incorret, it is not valid UTF16LE string (byte sequence). In that case the exception is raised:

```
PHP Notice – yii\base\ErrorException
iconv(): Detected an incomplete multibyte character in input string
```

That is fine. But the strange thins is - even if I wrap the iconv() all into try/catch, the Exception is not catched and spring up to the top level uncatched anyway. What's wrong with Exception handling?

Comment: Does it work if you use `\Exception` instead of `Exception`?

Comment: Indeed, it works for any variant of \ErrorException or \Exception as well. But will stay with the full yii\base\ErrorException to be clear.

Comment: This means that `Exception` is incorrectly resolved, probably to something like `app\controllers\Exception` instead of just `Exception`. Make sure that you're in global namespace (no `namespace` keyword in this file) and you're no using `Exception` name already in this context (no `use some\namespace\Exception` or `use some\namespace\SomeException as Exception`).

Comment: No. Of course I am in my own workspace, i.e. 'namespace app\models'. Obviously, I guess, I should not expect to use PHP generic Exception in Yii application, this is somehow opposite to the intuition available in other OO(-like) languages with generic Exception.

Comment: You should read how namespaces work. PHP does not make any assumptions about how your project is structured or what framework is used. All non-absolute FQN are resolved as relative to current namespace. So `Exception` inside of `app\models` namespace will be resolved to `app\models\Exception`. You need to either use absolute FQN (`\Exception`) or import exception explicitly (`use Exception`). I'm actually surprised that `catch (yii\base\ErrorException $ex)` worked - it should be resolved to `app\models\yii\base\ErrorException` which does not exist.

Comment: And catching generic exceptions like `\Exception` or `\Throwable` is common thing, you shouldn't bound your app to Yii too much. Relying on framework-agnostic interfaces usually gives less trouble on migration or framework/library change.

Answer (score 0):

One had to catch `ErrorException` from the Yii framework:

```
try {
    $tmp = iconv('UTF-16LE', 'UTF-8', $notes); 
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    $tmp = 'Multibyte conversion error: '+$ex->message;
} catch (yii\base\ErrorException $ex) {
    $tmp = 'Multibyte conversion error (from Yii2): '.$ex->getName();
}
```

Comment: You probably have something like `use yii\base\Exception;` Thanks to that your first catch applies only to exceptions that extends `yii\base\Exception` while yii\base\ErrorExceptions extends \ErrorException directly.